# How to set iterated value to 0 if a max value is met

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have variables `startTime` and `iterateTimes`, I'd like to add 20 min to `startTime` for `iterateTimes` then repeat. Here is the code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;

CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `ID` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `testTime` TIME,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_test` PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS setCorrectAppointmentTime;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE setCorrectAppointmentTime()
BEGIN
    DECLARE iterateTimes INT;
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE totalRows INT;
    -- every 3 time, the testTime value should be reset to 08:00:00
    SET iterateTimes = 3;
    SET totalRows = 7;
    SET i = 0;
    loop_label: LOOP
    IF i > totalRows THEN
        LEAVE loop_label;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (UUID(), AddTime('08:00:00', SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC('00:20:00') * i)));
    SET i = i + 1;
    
    ITERATE loop_label;
    END LOOP loop_label;
    SELECT iterateTimes;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL setCorrectAppointmentTime;
SELECT * FROM test;
```

This code output the following values:

[image]

However, I'd like the 4th row to the end to repeat the first 3 rows, i.e. the values of column `testTime` should be

```
08:00:00
08:20:00
08:40:00
08:00:00
08:20:00
08:40:00
08:00:00
08:20:00
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `test` (
>     `ID` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
>     `testTime` TIME,
>     CONSTRAINT `PK_test` PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
> );
> ```

> ```
> SET @start_time = '08:00:00';
> SET @range_length = '00:20:00';
> SET @rows_in_block = 3;
> SET @rows_amount = 7;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test
> WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
>     SELECT 0 num
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT num + 1 FROM cte WHERE num < @rows_amount - 1
> )
> SELECT UUID(), 
>        ADDTIME(@start_time, SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(@range_length) * (num MOD @rows_in_block)))
> FROM cte;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM test
> ```
>
> ```
> ID                                   | testTime
> :----------------------------------- | :-------
> 8dc84df5-d7f7-11ec-a90c-00163e64f9cc | 08:00:00
> 8dc850c1-d7f7-11ec-a90c-00163e64f9cc | 08:20:00
> 8dc8523f-d7f7-11ec-a90c-00163e64f9cc | 08:40:00
> 8dc8538f-d7f7-11ec-a90c-00163e64f9cc | 08:00:00
> 8dc85443-d7f7-11ec-a90c-00163e64f9cc | 08:20:00
> 8dc854f3-d7f7-11ec-a90c-00163e64f9cc | 08:40:00
> 8dc85597-d7f7-11ec-a90c-00163e64f9cc | 08:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=27cc3315caef9916680644de52235857)*